# How many jobs can be run at a time?

Tags: php, google-bigquery

I am looking to possibly sent queries to bigquery as aysnc jobs, however I do not know if this is actually a viable process.

Small run down:

1. get request
2. generate query
3. send async query
4. continue on to finish code

Id like to do this because as of right now the longest part of the script is waiting for bigquery to send back a reply. I do not use this reply for anything as its all streaming inserts, and I have not been able to find out what limitations there are on bigquery jobs.

Comment: What you want to do, streaming insert or run async queries?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Comment: Ideally id like to know the difference with bigquery on how it handles streaming vs async, could async potentially allow you to end the process sooner if you don't need to wait for a reply?

Comment: Async is a fire-and-forget technology, so the script doesn't need to wait for a reply. You can later pool for the result of the returned Job ID and consume later the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about running queries via `jobs.query()` or `jobs.insert()`, the quota limits can be found on the [Quota Policy page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#queries) of the BigQuery documentation.  In particular:

> Concurrent rate limit (applies to on-demand queries only): [...] **up to 20 concurrent queries**. Queries that return cached results, or queries configured using the dryRun property, do not count against this limit.

(some details about job size removed, emphasis mine)

If you are thinking about moving from synchronous `jobs.query()` to using the asynchronous `jobs.insert()`, you may find the [Querying Data page](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data) from our documentation useful as well.